# Can I create a network adapter driver that Windows can't use?

Tags: windows-10, networking

I highly suspect that there is no way you can setup a firewall to stop Windows internal workings to communicate with the internet.

So to kill all connectivity with Windows 10 I intentionally disabled ipv4 and piv6 from Windows own network adapter drivers to completely disable Windows 10's connectivity. What I would like to do is add another network adapter that Windows can't use but is completely operational for any other non Windows apps installed on the same machine.

Example: Virtualbox uses its own network drivers using a bridge adapter. Windows can't use this driver only Virtualbox can.

Can something like that be created is there software to make such a thing?

Image description: The pink area is what I want, my own ethernet adapter just for my apps just for my personal use that I route my specified installed software to utilize.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean something that somehow gets Internet access to the VM with the network adapters being disabled in the VM?

Comment: No! I want internet access like the VM does with using its own network adapter driver.

Comment: I will delete my answer . I have not seen a Host Only machine freely connected to the internet and I have done this for a long time. I am totally out of ideas.

Comment: @John Thanks for trying to help. This current setup makes for the ultimate sandbox. This way I never have to worry about the physical host machine ever getting infected or corrupted by connectivity related data damage. The VM can but is devoid of any personal data.